# DOJO: TreeGrid - keep expanded nodes open after page reload

Tags: javascript, dojo, treegrid

Is it possible to keep exanded nodes open after page reload in LazyTreeGrid or TreeGrid ?

Maybe I could read the list of open nodes and maybe it is possible to set which nodes are to be expanded at startup ?

Help please :)

Answer (score 0):

the cookie plugin could help you on this one:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/Cookie.html

It keeps the grid persistent by saving the grid properties in a cookie.

Lucian

Comment: AFAIK EnhancedGrid is not a Tree at all. Thx anyway.

Comment: treegrid extends datagrid and EnhancedGrid does too. grid has some persistence stuff, for example keepSelection property.

Comment: Thats true. I know how to maintain selectetion, scroll and sorting state using DataGrid methods. But I don't know how to get/set expanded rows in TreeGrid/LazyTreeGrid. Thats the problem here.